# How to transform a letter (saved in a byte) into a long? (NASM Assembly)

Tags: assembly, hex, nasm

Right now I'm trying to transform a .byte type variable (which can hold values of 'A','B','C','D' or 'E') (hex letters) into their decimal equivalents (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, and 15 respectively)

```
.data:
bit: .byte 'A'
result: .long 0

.letters:
movb bit, %ah
movb $'A', %al
subb %al,%ah
movb %ah, result
addl $10, result
```

But, when I run the code, result is equal to the result I want +7. Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That isn't NASM source, it's GNU assembler, using its default AT&T syntax mode.

Answer (score 0):

You're labeling your question with wrong tag `nasm` but the code looks like `gas`.

If you want to convert letters **'A','B','C','D','E'** to numbers **10,11,12,13,14** stored in `result` as an 32bit unsigned integer, load the hexadecimal letter to a register, e.g. `MOVZX EAX,byte ptr [bit]`  and then subtract the constant value 'A' from the register and add 10. This can be made in one step, e.g. `ADD EAX,10 - 'A'`.
In your AT&T syntax it would be

```
movzb bit,%eax
addl $10 - 'A',%eax
movl %eax,result
```

When `bit` contains letter 'B', the `result` will be 11 (0x0000000B) etc.
If you will need other hexadecimal digits 0..9, a..f, search for *conversion from hexadecimal.*

Comment: Not `$10-$'A'`, that would try to subtract the address of a symbol `$A`.  You want `$10 - 'A'`.  The `$` doesn't decorate individual numbers, it decorates the entire *expression*.  Also, the Intel-syntax version would be `movzx eax, byte ptr [bit]`, because nothing implies the source operand size.  (This is GAS, not MASM.  `bit: .byte ...` doesn't imply a size for `[bit]` in `.intel_syntax noprefix` mode.)  The standard AT&T syntax mnemonic for a byte load is `movzb bit, %eax`, or `movzbl bit, %eax` if you want to be explicit about the destination.